# Python RegEx String Parsing with inconsistent data

Tags: python, regex

I have a string that I need to extract values out of. The problem is the string is inconsistent. Here's an example of the script that has the string within it.

```
import re

RAW_Data = "Name Multiple Words Zero Row* (78.59/0) Name Multiple Words2* (96/24.56) Name Multiple Words3* (0/32.45) Name Multiple Words4* (96/12.58) Name Multiple Words5* (96/0) Name Multiple Words Zero Row6* (0) Name Multiple Words7* (96/95.57) Name Multiple Words Zero Row8* (0) Name Multiple Words9*"

First_Num = re.findall(r'\((.*?)\/*', RAW_Data)
Seg_Length = re.findall(r'\/(.*?)\)', RAW_Data)
#WithinParenthesis = re.findall(r'\((.*?)\)', RAW_Data) #This works correctly

print First_Num
print Seg_Length

del RAW_Data
```

What I need to get out of the string are all values within the parenthesis.  However, I need some logic that will handle the absence of the "/" between the numbers.  Basically if the "/" doesn't exist make both values for First_Num and Seg_Length equal to "0".  I hope this makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a simple regex and add some programming logic:

```
import re
rx = r'\(([^)]+)\)'
string = """Name Multiple Words Zero Row* (78.59/0) Name Multiple Words2* (96/24.56) Name Multiple Words3* (0/32.45) Name Multiple Words4* (96/12.58) Name Multiple Words5* (96/0) Name Multiple Words Zero Row6* (0) Name Multiple Words7* (96/95.57) Name Multiple Words Zero Row8* (0) Name Multiple Words9*"""

for match in re.finditer(rx, string):
    parts = match.group(1).split('/')
    First_Num = parts[0]
    try:
        Seg_Length = parts[1]
    except IndexError:
        Seg_Length = None

    print "First_Num, Seg_Length: ", First_Num, Seg_Length
```

You might get along with a regex alone solution (e.g. with conditional regex), but this approach is likely to be still understood in three months. See a demo on <kbd>[ideone.com](http://ideone.com/vAAETC)</kbd>.

Comment: That looks like it'll work Jan.  I ran it on some sample data, and it's doing exactly what I want it to.  Awesome!  Thanks

Comment: @user1457123: Glad to help :)

Comment: Jan, do you have any suggestions on how I can run this within a nested loop?  When I try, I get the last set of values for First_Num and Seg_Length only.  Maybe I should post a new question for this?

Comment: Yes, post a new question :-)

Answer (score 0):

You are attempting to find values on each side of '/' that you know may not exist.  Pull back to the always known condition for your initial search.  Use a Regular Expression to findall of data within parenthesis.  Then process these based on if '/' is in the value.